# how do I extract text from a nested xml using xmlpullparser in android?

Tags: android, xml, nested, xmlpullparser

```
<doc>
 <element>
  text
     <item>
     text1
     </item>
     <item>
     text2
     </item>
  text3
 </element>
 <element>
  another text
 </element>


 ...
</doc>
```

And I want to extract text to an string like this:

```
 "text text1 text2 text3"
```

"item" tags are nested inside "element"

Im using xmlpullparser in Android but I could use any other parser if it make things easier.
tx.

Comment: If strings are all you're after, why not just you use the strings.xml file.  Its a lot simpler.

Comment: if you want text without the tags, you can use String.replace with a regex or something

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean. strings.xml from android SDK? this is a third-party file I need to parse

Comment: Yes but the tag item is different in some cases has attributes and so on.. The real file is wide more complicated than this snippet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16069754/236743

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I parse similar xml files.  Here is an example.  You'll need to add error checking as appropriate.

```
void loadXML(XmlPullParser xpp) {
    int eventType = xpp.next();
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && 0 == XML_ELEMENT_TAG.compareTo(xpp.getName())) {
            loadElement(xpp);
        }

        eventType = xpp.next();   
    }
}

private void loadElement(XmlPullParser xpp) {

    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
    if ( eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && 0 == XML_ELEMENT_TAG.compareTo(xpp.getName()) ) {
        eventType = xpp.next();
        while ( eventType != XmlPullParser.END_TAG || 0 != XML_ELEMENT_TAG.compareTo(xpp.getName()) ) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG &&     0 == XML_ITEM_TAG.compareTo(xpp.getName())) {
                loadItem(xpp);
            }

            eventType = xpp.next();   
        }
    } 
}

private void loadItem(XmlPullParser xpp) {

    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
    if ( eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && 0 == XML_ITEM_TAG.compareTo(xpp.getName()) ) {

        eventType = xpp.next();
        while ( eventType != XmlPullParser.END_TAG || 0 != XML_ITEM_TAG.compareTo(xpp.getName()) ) {

            // Get attributes.
            String  attr = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, XML_MY_ATTR); 
            String  text = null;

            // Get item text if present.
            eventType = xpp.next();
            while ( eventType != XmlPullParser.END_TAG || 0 != XML_ITEM_TAG.compareTo(xpp.getName()) ) {
                if ( eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT ) {
                    text = xpp.getText();
                } 

                eventType = xpp.next();
            }

            eventType = xpp.next();   
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: It worked!  Not exactly like this because of my XML, but enough to put me on my own feet. tx a lot

Answer (score -4):

Have you had a look at the [Android documentation for XMLPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)?  It pretty easy to follow.  Let us know if that solves your problem.

Comment: I did and also xmlpullparser website. Didn't find about nested tags.

Comment: @MikeD  Negative. That documentation is not easy to follow for nested xml tags.