# XmlPullParser: get inner text including XML tags

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

Suppose you have an XML document like so:

```
<root>
  That was a <b boldness="very">very bold</b> move.
</root>
```

Suppose the `XmlPullParser` is on the opening tag for root. Is there a handy method to read all text within `root` to a `String`, sort of like `innerHtml` in DOM?

Or do I have to write a utility method myself that recreates the parsed tag? This of course seems like a waste of time to me.

```
String myDesiredString = "That was a <b boldness=\"very\">very bold</b> move."
```

Comment: I'm afraid you're bound to write your own function to parse given xml as you wanted to.

Comment: Aw man. :( Maybe I can use SAX parsing though?

Comment: Yet I think that you have to reconstruct the bold tag yourself whilst parsing the data. Similarly to pull parser, afaik, SAX parser does handle the bold tag and not give you "inner xml".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This method should about cover it, but does not deal with singleton tags or namespaces.

```
public static String getInnerXml(XmlPullParser parser)
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int depth = 1;
    while (depth != 0) {
        switch (parser.next()) {
        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
            depth--;
            if (depth > 0) {
                sb.append("</" + parser.getName() + ">");
            }
            break;
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            depth++;
            StringBuilder attrs = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < parser.getAttributeCount(); i++) {
                attrs.append(parser.getAttributeName(i) + "=\""
                        + parser.getAttributeValue(i) + "\" ");
            }
            sb.append("<" + parser.getName() + " " + attrs.toString() + ">");
            break;
        default:
            sb.append(parser.getText());
            break;
        }
    }
    String content = sb.toString();
    return content;
}
```