# Get the inner XML using XPath?

Tags: xpath

This is my XML

```
    <my_xml>
     <record>
      <p>hello <b>world</b> this is some html</p>
     </record>
    </my_xml>
```

Can I use XPath to return the following?

```
    <p>hello <b>world</b> this is some html</p>
```

Comment: You can get the `p` node, then you can serialize it back to a string. in which context (application, language, ...) are you using xpath?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "return".  How are you actually executing the XPath expression - what programming language and what tool/library are you using, and can you post a relevant snippet of the code you've tried so far?

Comment: which language you are using like `Ruby`,`Pyhton` etc..?

Answer (score 1):

```
my_xml/record/child::*
```

child::* selects all element children of the context node
[see details](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is, no. You can't accomplish this with XPath, but, once you select the parent node (i.e. "record" in your example), you should be able to manipulate it in whichever language you are using to parse the XML. Unfortunately, it may not be "easy".

It sounds like you would want something like the [innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) property, but for XML DOM instead of the HTML DOM. Unfortunately, nothing like this exists for the XML DOM. If you don't care about the nodes themselves, you could use the [textContent](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_textcontent.asp) property; in the case of your example, you would get `"hello world this is some html"`, which doesn't seem to be what you want.

Check out [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069425/xmlpullparser-get-inner-text-including-xml-tags), which includes a parsing algorithm in Java. It seems that you will need to write a similar algorithm in whichever language you're using to parse the XML.

Comment: Most languages already provide XML parsers with methods like `asXML` that would serialize an object corresponding to a node to XML.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for this in the future, this IS very much possible to do using a DOT, that will return the entire node content as text (at least in MSSQL xpath it does).

```
'(/my_xml/record/.)[1]'
```