# XmlPullParser - Parse nested tag

Tags: java, android, arrays, xmlpullparser, android-xmlpullparser

I have this XML:

```
<menu>
    <day name="monday">
        <meal name="BREAKFAST">
            <counter name="Bread">
               <dish>
                   <name>Plain Bagel</name>
               </dish>
            <counter/>
        <meal/>
    <day/>
    <day name="tuesday">
        <meal name="LUNCH">
            <counter name="Other">
               <dish>
                   <name>Cheese Bagel</name>
               </dish>
            <counter/>
        <meal/>
    <day/>
<menu/>
```

Now here is what I am trying to do, if the day tag's attribute is equal to monday. And then meals tag attribute is equal to `BREAKFAST`, then I want to get the counter's attribute. "Bread".

I have set up xml pull parser, but I am struggling getting this value. Here is what I have tried, I now I see that it can't and won't work... So any help on how I could set it up to do this would be great.

```
while (eventType != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        String tagName = xmlData.getName();

        switch (eventType) {
            case XmlResourceParser.START_TAG:
                if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("day")) {
                    if (xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "name").equalsIgnoreCase(day)) {
                        if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("meal")) {
                            mealArray.add(xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                            Log.i(TAG, xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                        }
                    }


                }
                break;
            case XmlResourceParser.TEXT:
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                break;
        }
        eventType = xmlData.next();
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You would need to add logic for parsing nested tags:

A very simple example to help you move ahead:

I parsed this String:

`<menu><day name=\"monday\"><meal name=\"BREAKFAST\"><meal/><day/></menu>`

Code:

```
try {
    factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

    xpp.setInput(new StringReader("<menu><day name=\"monday\"><meal name=\"BREAKFAST\"><meal/><day/></menu>"));
    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
    while (eventType != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        String tagName = xpp.getName();

        switch (eventType) {
            case XmlResourceParser.START_TAG:
                if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("day")) {
                    if (xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "name").equalsIgnoreCase("MONDAY")) {
                        int eventType2 = xpp.next();
                        while (eventType2 != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                            String tagName2 = xpp.getName();
                            switch (eventType2) {
                            case XmlResourceParser.START_TAG:
                                if (tagName2.equalsIgnoreCase("meal")) {
                                    Log.i("tag", "meal: " + xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                                }
                                break;
                            case XmlResourceParser.TEXT:
                                break;
                            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                                break;
                            }
                            eventType2 = xpp.next();
                        }
                    }
                }
            break;
            case XmlResourceParser.TEXT:
            break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
            break;
        }
        eventType = xpp.next();
    }

} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You see the difference, right?

I added this, basically, just after getting the day what I wanted. (In my case, hard coded String `"Monday"`.)

```
int eventType2 = xpp.next();
```

And based upon that `eventType2`, retrieved `tagName2` which would be for "meal"

A [better example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9469483/1777090) to help you write your logic in a nice manner.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Well, just looking logically at your switch statement right now:

```
String tagName = xmlData.getName();


            if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("day")) {
                if( . . . ) {
                    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("meal")) {
                      //do something
                    }
                }
```

Do you see the issue right there? You won't EVER have `tagName.equals("day")` and `tagName.equals("meal")` both be true! Keep getting the child of the xmlData and get it's name, then do another if statement.

You need to update the value of `tagName` after every if.

Comment: yes I see the problem, just not sure how to fix it. And I kind of see what your saying could you post some code or more to explain it some more? Cause I only want to the when its Monday and BREAKFAST

Answer (score 3):

### Main Idea

store your information in a local variable and then check if visited tags is equal to your desired pattern or not, if it is, do what you want. here is the idea:

```
  String currentDay;
  String mealOfCurrentDay;

  while (eventType != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        String tagName = xmlData.getName();

        switch (eventType) {
            case XmlResourceParser.START_TAG:
                if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("day")) 
                       currentDay = xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                }
                if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("meal")) 
                       mealOfCurrentDay = xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                }
                if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("counter ")){
                    // now we must check our stored pattern
                    // step one: day must be monday
                    if(currentDay != null && currentDay.equalsIgnoreCase("monday")){
                         // step tow: meal must be BREAKFAST
                         if(mealOfCurrentDay!= null && mealOfCurrentDay.equalsIgnoreCase("BREAKFAST")){
                              counter = xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                              // Wow we have done :-)
                         }
                         else{
                          // no, it is not my desierd pattern so I clear my history
                             currentDay = "";
                             mealOfCurrentDay = "";
                         }  
                    }else{
                        // no, it is not my desierd pattern so I clear my history
                        currentDay = "";
                        mealOfCurrentDay = "";
                    }
                }
                break;
            case XmlResourceParser.TEXT:
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                break;
        }
        eventType = xmlData.next();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly your XML is not in correct format.
Check at any website. Say on this [XML Validator](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/)

The closing tag should be like this

> < meal > < /meal >
>
> not => < meal >< meal />

After correcting XML as *response* string below,
You can try this code, its working

```
    String response = "<menu><day name=\"monday\"><meal name=\"BREAKFAST\"><counter name=\"Bread\"><dish><name>Plain Bagel</name></dish></counter></meal></day><day name=\"tuesday\"><meal name=\"LUNCH\"><counter name=\"Other\"><dish><name>Cheese Bagel</name></dish></counter></meal></day></menu>";
    Document doc;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource isr = new InputSource();
    isr.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(response));

    doc = db.parse(isr);
    
    try{
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("day");
        for (int i = 0; i <= nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node nNode = nodes.item(i);
            
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                
                
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                System.out.println("day"+eElement.getAttribute("name"));
                System.out.println("meal"+eElement.getElementsByTagName("meal").item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
                System.out.println("counter"+eElement.getElementsByTagName("counter").item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
                System.out.println("dish :" + eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent());

            }
        }
    
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        
    }
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: So basically you are recommending NOT using XMLPullParser for getting nested tags?

Answer (score 2):

```
       while (eventType != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        String tagName = xmlData.getName();

        switch (eventType) {
           case XmlResourceParser.START_TAG:
                if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("day")) {
                    day = xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                }
                if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("meal")) {
                    meal = xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                }
                if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("counter")) {
                    counter = xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                }

                break;
            case XmlResourceParser.TEXT:
                data += xmlData.getText();
                if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                    name= xmlData.getText();
                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                if (tagName.equals("day")) {
                    recordsFound++;

                }
                break;
        }
        publishProgress(new String[]{day,meal,counter});
        eventType = xmlData.next();

    }
```

First, breaks are missing in your switch-case statement.
Secondly, attributes are always parsed from START_TAG case. text inside tags are parsed in TEXT case and END_TAG is useful for making objects or arraylists based on its nesting.

onProgressUpdate must look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
   super.onProgressUpdate(values);
   if (values.length == 0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "no data");
    }
    else {
       String day = values[0];
       String meal= values[1];
       String counter= values[2];
    }

}
```

Comment: what do I change in `onProgressUpdate`

Comment: okay I think the publish progress needs to be different because or something because when I add logs in the onProgressUpdate it logs it way to many times

Comment: how do I not get all of the nested tags just the ones under a certain day? could you look at this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476359/how-to-get-child-node-when-using-xmlpullparser

Answer (score 2):

First, your XML is broken, look at the end tags. Should be:

```
<menu>
<day name="monday">
    <meal name="BREAKFAST">
        <counter name="Bread">
           <dish>
               <name>Plain Bagel</name>
           </dish>
        </counter>
    /</meal>
</day>
<day name="tuesday">
    <meal name="LUNCH">
        <counter name="Other">
           <dish>
               <name>Cheese Bagel</name>
           </dish>
       </counter>
    </meal>
</day>
```

Second, consider using not a pull parser, you are using a lot of code lines but there are shorter ways to your goal (e.g. [XMLBeam](http://xmlbeam.org) (**Disclosure: I'm affiliated with that project**)):

```
public class Test {
@XBDocURL("res://menu.xml")
public interface Menu {
    @XBRead("//day[@name='monday']/meal[@name='BREAKFAST']/counter/@name")
    String getCounterName();
}

@Test
public void testMenu() throws IOException {
    String name = new XBProjector().io().fromURLAnnotation(Menu.class).getCounterName();
    assertEquals("Bread", name);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

**Use XPath and be in peace**

```
package xml;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class XPathTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse("sample.xml");

    XPathFactory xpathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xpathfactory.newXPath()
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("string(/menu/day[@name='monday']/meal[@name='BREAKFAST']/counter/@name))");
    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
return (String)result;
}
}
```