# Show ratings of item in uitableview cell

Tags: javascript, ios, xml, json, parse-platform

I am currently working on a iOS app that shows 30 menu items in a UITableView and Users can then rate theses items out of 5 starts on the detail page which is shown when a user taps the cell.

Now in the cell currently is just the title of the item, now what I want to do is have the title of the item and the current avg. rating of the item below the title. Now I know how to create the cell, but I am having trouble getting the data of the current rating of the movie in a efficient way.

I am currently using Parse.com as my back-end. Now when a user submits a rating it is saved to my class on Parse called Ratings. And the title of the item and the number of stars given is saved.

Now I am trying to think of the most efficient way to get the average number of stars for the item and put it in the UITableViewCell. First I thought about just performing a cloud code function that would query all 30 item, and average the ratings like is done in the parse.com docs https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions.

The problem here is that there are 30 or more items and each query then uses an API request which, then gets up high pretty quick. So I have ruled out that option. Another would be to only display 5 items at a time and then load then next 5 when the user scrolls down, but users typically scroll through multiple items very quickly and would still look at all 30 items on the menu, so that doesn't solve my problem.

Now I also have my own server where I currently store some of the items being served. I was thinking if there is a way to make an xml file, or JSON, and when a user saves an item I save it to Parse. And then also save it this file.

So here is what I am thinking and where I get stuck. I would make a Cloud Code Job, using the Parse.com Javascript SDK, and it would run once a day. And I would have this function preform one query the retrieves all the ratings that were saved to my Ratings class in the last day. And this would give me all the objects. Now this is where I get stuck: how do I get this file onto my server from the Parse.com SDK and how do I just save the new ratings, to this file?

Of course I am open to all other suggestions of ways to get around this and minimize my API requests. I was thinking also possibly use the Parse.com hosting to host the xml or JSON file?

Or just a completely different way to do it, that I haven't mentioned.

I know this is a long question, and I did my best to explain it, if you have any question please ask.

Thanks for the help in advance. I really appreciate it :)

**EDIT**

Something I forgot to mention is that these items change daily, and I have multiple restaurants each with their own items, so it's 30 * # of restaurants. So when I am displaying lets say 30 items in the table view Im not sure how I get all the ratings in two queries (with the extra class, don't I still need to query for each item)?

**EDIT 2**

Okay so now I have an NSMutableArray filled with the ratings, that I get returned from my query. But lets say I have the items "one", "two" and "three" in my table view. And only "one" and "three" have been rated, then I get the two ratings back for those items, and if in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method I just do. something like

```
cell.rating = ratingsArray[indexRow.path];
```

Then the item two will have what should be threes rating...

Do you see the problem? And how I could get around it?

Thanks

Comment: This is an interesting question, and i faced the same issue. You can try implement a 'RatingsAverage' class in Parse SDK, with attributes :"menu item", "nbRatings" "sumOfStars". When you load the data for the tableview, you have to do two API requests, one for the items and one for the 'RatingsAverage', and perform the pairing in your app. 'RatingsAverage' items are only updated when a new rating is created for an object, but even if you need more API requests in this case, you will save much more API requests from the tableview display.

Comment: Yup you might want another class that save the summarized rating.

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo okay, but I think I didn't explain a part of the question, could you see the edit what you have a chance

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Cloud Code Jobs or anything else. You can simply create another class having these attributes: `itemId`, `numberOfVotes`, `averageRating`. When user post a new rating, do the following on his device:

```
averageRating = (averageRating*numberOfVotes + userVote) / (numberOfVotes+1)
numberOfVotes++
```

and store these two values in the cloud. When you need to display average rating, simply fetch `averageRating` value for the item.

**EDIT**

When I said about an extra class, I meant that you don't need to store every rating in the cloud. You can use just one class and store only an average rating for each item and a number of votes. And you can fetch average ratings for multiple items with a single API call by making a [query](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-constraints/iOS) like that:

```
NSArray *ids = @[@"1",
                 @"2",
                 @"3"];
[query whereKey:@"itemId" containedIn:ids];
```

If you want to store each user's ratings (to check if user has already voted on that particular items or to display his ratings on another device), you can store them in iCloud container, that way you will only need one API call when user casts a vote and one call when user fetches 30 (or any number) of items.

You can also look into using CloudKit instead of Parse, if you don't need to support iOS 7 and lower.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the post could you see edit Im not sure this would work for me

Comment: @iqueqiorio I made an addition to answer.

Comment: Okay I get it now, but one more thing is I am still going to have my Regular Rating Class to save it for the user so I can show theres, and then if the user updates there rating I can query that class and if they haven't already rated the item your code works, but if they have your code of saving to the AverageRating class does, so what would I resave the average rating as if this is an update to the rating?

Comment: @iqueqiorio use the following formula to subtract user's rating `averageRating = (averageRating*numberOfVotes - oldUserVote) / (numberOfVotes-1)` (don't forget to add division by zero check) and after that add new rating using `averageRating = (averageRating*numberOfVotes + newUserVote) / numberOfVotes`

Comment: okay but I need to query AverageRating before I save there right? how else do you know what the average rating is and what the number of votes it?

Comment: @iqueqiorio Yes, you do

Comment: So I got the query working but now I am having some trouble with posting the ratings in the tableview could you see edit

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have two properties.  allStars and numboerOfReviews.  Each time someone writes a review,

`[movie incrementKey"allStars" by whatever the user selects]`

`[movie incrementKey:"numberOfReviews" byAmount:1]`

Then handle avg client side.  allStars/numberOrReviews

These should be properties on your MovieObject, and they will be included when you query the movies, since they are primitives and not pointers. So when you perform a PFQuery, if successful, you get an array of PFObjects.  Set you tableViewDataArray to the array your query returns.  Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you access you properties, like (tableViewDataArray[indexPath.row] as Movie).numberOfStars