# Add icons to alternating UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an NSMutableArray filled with the ratings of items, that I get returned from my query (web). Now lets say I have the items "one", "two" and "three" in my table view. And only "one" and "three" have been rated, then I get the two ratings back for those items when I do my query, and if in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`method I just do. something like

```
cell.rating = ratingsArray[indexRow.path];
```

Where `cell.rating` is an attribute in my cell

Then the item two will have what should be threes rating...

Do you see the problem? And how I could get around it?

Thanks for the help :)

**EDIT**

```
myArray = @[@"one", @"two", @"three"];



PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AverageRating"];
[query whereKey:@"item" containedIn:myArray];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    if (results) {
        NSLog(@"%@", results);

    }
}];
```

And I don't know which have been rated.

Answer (score 0):

Now the value in the array may be [4,3]

The value in the array should be [4,0,3] as 4,0,3 represent individual ratings
hence the problem can be fixed

ir return 0 or any unused valid value for rating when there is none available

Comment: But only the "one", and "three" have been rating so on my back end there is no 0, for the "two" value... I need to like match the item to its rating or something do you know what I mean?

Comment: how do you know one and three has values and not two?

Comment: I am using parse.com as my back end and doing a contained in query, and Im not sure it can return 0, for a value that is not found...

Comment: if a value is not found add a value 0 into the array

Comment: And I know three and one have been rated because I rated them, I am doing this, for when my tableview has real items and not all of them will have been rated

Comment: are you familiar with parse.com? see edit, it returns an NSArray not each value indiviaulally

Comment: yes i am aware and worked with parse for multiple projects..It returns the array that you added as value into the table .so the default condition is to make it 0 primarly and as rating for  all the keys. change it in parse according to the position when a keys value is changed

Comment: sorry, Im not quite sure what you mean, what am I supposed to change in parse?

Comment: The rating is corresponding to a certain set for eg.cinema...so in the table you should have rating of all cinemas even if there is no value available for the second film.there should be a relation between cinema and rating by that table

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good use for NSNull. Put NSNull into the array for "no rating", and then when you are determining what to display in your UI, see if the value in the array is NSNull or not.

Comment: but it returns an array

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a way to determine if the cell has a rating or not. Here is a simple solution. Instead of using an NSMutableArray to hold your ratings, you should use an NSMutableDictionary.

The dictionary should be structured so that the "Keys" can be the index to which the rating corresponds. So your dictionary can look something like this:

Key: 0 Value: rating for first cell
Key: 2 Value: rating for cell three

Inside your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, you can do a check to see if the dictionary contains a key corresponding to the indexPath.Row value and if it does, you can set a rating for the cell.

Code:
Get your data represented using a dictionary instead:

```
NSMutableDictionary *ratingsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[myDictionary setObject:rating1 forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]
[myDictionary setObject:rating3 forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]]
```

Add this to your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

```
if ([ratingsDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.Row]])
{
    cell.rating = [ratingsDictionary valueForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.Row]];
}
```

Comment: yes I was thinking about doing something like this, but I am having trouble setting it up could you elaborate/ post some sample code I would really appreciate it

Comment: Added some code. Untested, but it should point you in the right direction. Hope it helps!

Comment: okay got it, but this would work for this very simple case, in reality, Im not going to know that item "two" hasn't been rated, do you see what I mean?

Comment: In this question I restated the problem of edit two in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476359/show-ratings-of-item-in-uitableview-cell